# MissingRequirementError when Compiling Scala code with Global.Run

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-compiler

I'm trying to compile Scala files programmatically by using an instance of `Global.Run`:

```
val settings = new Settings                 
val reporter = new ConsoleReporter(settings)
val compiler = new Global(settings, reporter)
val run = new compiler.Run // MissingRequirementError
run compile List(path)
```

Unfortunately I get a `MissingRequirementError` saying:

> object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found

So my **question** is how can I compile a file programmatically by using the `Run` class, or what am I doing wrong here?

I tried to figure out whether I could change the `settings` in order to get it work. Actually I need a list of classes that are in the Scala file at `path`, not necessarily a fully runnable output. It would therefore be fine if symbols remained unresolved (if I could run a subset of the compiler phases).

I also at [Writing Scala Compiler Plugins](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140), but if I can run it by instanciating a Compiler Run object, I'd prefer this solution. I also stumbled across [Is the Scala compiler reentrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961967/is-the-scala-compiler-reentrant) (similar code, different question), which makes me think it might work the way I'm thinking of.

**Edit 1: Added Scala JARs to the `toolcp` (just sample code with absolute path!)**

According to a comment I adapted `scalac.bat`'s classpath population script to my Scala code:

```
// scalac.bat
// if "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
//   for %%f in ("!_SCALA_HOME!\lib\*") do call :add_cpath "%%f"
//   for /d %%f in ("!_SCALA_HOME!\lib\*") do call :add_cpath "%%f"
// )
new File("C:\\Program Files\\scala\\lib").listFiles.foreach(f => {
  settings.classpath.append(f.getAbsolutePath)
  settings.toolcp.append(f.getAbsolutePath)
})
```

Comment: Added all jars to your class path? Check scalac and see how it setups the classpath of what is to be compiled.

Comment: @pedrofurla I had appended it to `classpath`, but not to `toolcp` yet. I added some code, but it does not help (same error). Edited the question. Thanks for reading and commenting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it running, by using `bootclasspath` instead of `toolcp` (thanks to pedrofurla's hint):

```
val settings = new Settings
new File("C:\\Program Files\\scala\\lib").listFiles.foreach(f => {
  settings.classpath.append(f.getAbsolutePath)
  settings.bootclasspath.append(f.getAbsolutePath)
})

private val reporter = new ConsoleReporter(settings)
private val compiler = new Global(settings, reporter)

val run = new compiler.Run
run compile List(path)
```

The compiler attempts to compile the files now. However, this seems not to be exactly what `scalac.bat` does. It starts it with `-cp`, which is the normal classpath, whereas `bootclasspath` is passed with `-bootclasspath` on the console, as visible in `StandardScalaSettings` trait:

```
val bootclasspath = PathSetting ("-bootclasspath", "Override location of bootstrap class files.", Defaults.scalaBootClassPath)
```